# How do you change the vertical margin in a vis.js timeline?

Tags: javascript, css, timeline, vis.js

In each row of a vis.js timeline there is a margin of 5px. This is set as an inline style programmatically: the `height` of each row is specified by the library, and so is the `top` position and `transform` of each item in the row.

This means that setting these values yourself (for example, with `item.style = 'top: 0'`) fails because they are immediately overwritten by vis.js.

How would I change this margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin option described in the vis-timeline options list at https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options can be used to adjust the margins.

For example the below sets the horizontal and vertical margins for items to 0 pixels. It also sets the axis margin to 5 pixels to place items closer to time axis.

```js
var options = {
    margin : { 
        item: {horizontal:0, vertical:0},
        axis: 5       
    }
};
```

CSS can then be used to change the height of the items.

```css
.vis-box {
  height: 20px;
}
.vis-range {
  height : 20px;
}
```

Full example using these settings for a compact view:

```js
// DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
var container = document.getElementById("visualization");

// Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, content: "item 1", start: "2021-12-20" },
  { id: 2, content: "item 2", start: "2021-12-14" },
  { id: 3, content: "item 3", start: "2021-12-18" },
  { id: 4, content: "item 4", start: "2021-12-16", end: "2021-12-19" },
  { id: 5, content: "item 5", start: "2021-12-25" },
  { id: 6, content: "item 6", start: "2021-12-27", type: "point" },
]);

// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {
    margin : { 
        item: {horizontal:0, vertical:0},
        axis: 5       
    }
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.vis-box {
  height: 20px;
}
.vis-range {
  height : 20px;
}
.vis-item {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/standalone/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/styles/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you; I'm not sure how I missed that in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `!important`? Example: `top: 0 !important;`

This will ensure that this property will not be overwritten.

Comment: No, that does not work. By "overwritten", I mean the properties are literally overwritten in the DOM. If you drag the timeline, for example, an update call is made that resets `top`, `transform`, etc. Here's an example from the official demos: https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/basicUsage.html. Try changing `top: 5px` to `top: 0` for one of the items, and then drag or zoom. As soon as you move the timeline, the element resets its position.

Comment: If I only had one or two items, I could assign the elements a class and use `top: 0 !important` in that class. However, with hundreds or thousands of elements being fetched and generated on the fly, this solution doesn't work at all.